# Javascript removing an object element from an array in a clean way (not leaving a null ghost)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array:

```
var Array = {};
Array['elements'] = [];
Array['elements'][0]['name'] = "Sally";
Array['elements'][0]['age'] = "20";
Array['elements'][3]['name'] = "Jack";
Array['elements'][3]['age'] = "21";
Array['elements'][4]['name'] = "Megan";
Array['elements'][4]['age'] = "22";
```

I do not know how to remove Jack from the array to return a list of women only. Splice is mutable, and passing back the entire object seems inefficient, and cumbersome.

In PHP, you can:

```
unset($Array['elements'][3]);
```

I have tried

```
delete Array['elements'][3];
```

but that just yields a null value in its place, not really deleting the element, messing up everywhere else I am testing for elements. Is there a clean way to delete an element from an array based on its key?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code as written doesn't work since Array.elements[0] [3] and [4] are never defined, you can't add properties to them - firstly, I'd never overload `Array`, I wouldn't call that variable any variation of `Array` since it's not an Array; and finally just test for `null` if you insist on `.elements` being an Array (you could make it an Object instead, and you won't end up with a sparse array)

Comment: why are you adding to indices 0, 3 and 4 only? What is the significance of these numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *remove* items from an array by *splicing* it:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
var removed = a.splice(1,2)
```

`a` becomes:

```
[1,4,5]
```

And `removed` contains:

```
[2,3]
```

You can select a new, filtered list by referring to [Nidhin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58350394/779572).

---

<sup>As an aside, the code in your question *is not JavaScript*... Are you running that gibberish successfully somewhere?</sup>

Comment: then the indices for the entries will change

Comment: @Bravo Yes ... is that not the intention?

Comment: @svidgen `Are you running that gibberish successfully somewhere?` haha :D :D

Comment: @svidgen - since the initial attempt creates a sparse array, not sure what the intention is - it seems the indices are important (should use an object instead0

Comment: @Bravo Yeah, I'd read it as the indexes being incidental. But, you may be right. **Post an answer!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it uses splice though but it will leave your initial array as it is -

```
let array = [];
array.push({name:'Sally', age:20});
array.push({name:'Jack', age:21});
array.push({name:'Megan', age:22});
let newArray = [...array];
newArray.splice(1, 1);
```

Check this article https://jaketrent.com/post/remove-array-element-without-mutating/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `Array` as an variable name - it is the javascript Array object, you don't want to override that

Secondly, since `Array = {}`, calling it any variation of the word `Array` is misleading, it's an Object

Thirdly, you've created Array.elements as an array, but then populate only indices 0, 3, and 4 - so you've created a sparse array to begin with

Fourthly, the code you wrote doesn't even run, since you are trying to assign `.name` to `elements[0]` but at that point `elements[0]` is undefined, so you'll end up with an error, and the code stops running right there

What it looks like you want is `Array.elements = {}` - then you can add/delete any *key* you want

For example

```js
var obj = {};
obj.elements = {};
obj.elements[0] = {};
obj.elements[0].name = "Sally";
obj.elements[0].age = "20";
obj.elements[3] = {};
obj.elements[3].name = "Jack";
obj.elements[3].age = "21";
obj.elements[4] = {};
obj.elements[4].name = "Megan";
obj.elements[4].age = "22";

delete obj.elements[3];

for (let i in obj.elements) {
    console.log('Number', i, 'is', obj.elements[i].name);
}
```

When using elements as an Array, you'll see after your initial population of the array, you already have two **undefined** to begin with - see first console output

Note: however, `for...in` loop will skip those **undefined** elements

Also note, the undefined elements are actually "empty slots" - i.e. if you simply put `obj.elements[3] = undefined` that's not the same as `delete obj.elements[3]`

```js
var obj = {};
obj.elements = [];
obj.elements[0] = {};
obj.elements[0].name = "Sally";
obj.elements[0].age = "20";
obj.elements[3] = {};
obj.elements[3].name = "Jack";
obj.elements[3].age = "21";
obj.elements[4] = {};
obj.elements[4].name = "Megan";
obj.elements[4].age = "22";

console.log(obj.elements)

delete obj.elements[3];

console.log(obj.elements)
for (let i in obj.elements) {
    console.log('Number', i, 'is', obj.elements[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove Jack from the array, you can code like this:

Array['elements'].filter(e => e.name != 'Jack');